# What do I do to upgrade docker.io if it fails with apt upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, docker

I am trying to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 with a standard apt update && apt upgrade but I am getting a failure. What should I do to proceed and keep the system updated?

I'm getting the error:

```
Setting up docker.io (20.10.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) ...
mv: cannot stat '/var/lib/docker.migrating/*': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
 installed docker.io package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker.io
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been reported and a workout was suggested here: https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/issues/170#issuecomment-826359558

Following the steps worked for me.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/docker.migrating
echo 'dummy' | sudo tee /var/lib/docker.migrating/workaround.txt
```

this will allow the stat '/var/lib/docker.migrating/*' to not fail with an error.

After the successful apt update docker.io run, you can remove the workaround dummy file:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/docker/workaround.txt
```

Comment: That didn't work for me.. but probably my docker.io upgrade issue is a different one.

Comment: I faced a slightly similar error related to the aufs storage driver, see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361206/docker-upgrade-failure-the-aufs-storage-driver-is-no-longer-supported